# Getting UTF-8 characters from SQL Server table into PHP using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, utf-8

I have a SQL Server table that contains country names translated into various languages. I am attempting to display this in a web page. However, what is stored in the database as `Amérique du Nord` comes out in PHP as `AmÃ©rique du Nord`

My PDO connection string is

```
sqlsrv:SERVER=<SERVER>;DATABASE=<DATABASE>
```

There is no charset option for SQL Server, but the default according to the documentation is UTF-8.

I have tried casting the column to `varbinary`, but that just gives me an ascii number that I have not been able to convert to a character. I have also tried a few variations of mb_character_encode which ended up making the characters Chinese.

For additional information:

I am on IIS 7.5, running PHP through FastCGI.

The script is sending the utf-8 header.

On other areas of the same page, I am successfully outputting UTF-8 that I am reading in from a .po file. Only text from the database query is mis-encoded.

Comment: `Ã©` is exactly `é` properly encoded as UTF-8 and misinterpreted as Windows-1252 or similar. Is your PHP application using UTF-8?

Comment: As far as I can tell it is - I am setting the header using `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and have set the `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` as well. Is there something else I need to set or change? (The application is on IIS)

Comment: The first item declares the page as UTF-8 (which doesn't mean it's actually using UTF-8). The second item is unrelated to page encoding AFAIK. Please let me link to the usual question.

Comment: The question you marked this as a duplicate of is responding to a question on a different platform (Apache) and a different database (MySQL). None of the settings in the answer to that question exist on MSSQL connections via PDO.

Comment: What encoding of table?

Comment: The character set is Unicode, the collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS